# Need Help Simplifying an Immutable.js Array of Objects update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm new to immutablejs and have managed to update a property of an object stored in an array of objects. My goal is to simplify my development but I feel like I'v made it more complicated.  Clearly, I'm missing something to make this simpler.

I created to stackblitz projects, one with the code without immutablejs https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-before-immutable , and one with immutablejs https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-after-immutable

(code below also).

I've seen some examples here where people use the second parameter of findIndex, but that function never got called for me. It also is not in the docs so I'm guessing it's not supported any more.

With Immutable.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { List } from 'immutable';

export default () => {

  const init = [{
    id: 101,
    interestLevel: 1
  },
  {
    id: 102,
    interestLevel: 0
  }];

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(init);

  const updateRow = (e) => {
    const id = parseInt(e.target.attributes['data-id'].value);

    const immutableMyArray = List(myArray);
    const index = List(myArray).findIndex((item) => {
      return item.id === id;
    });
    const myRow = immutableMyArray.get(index);
    myRow.interestLevel++;
    const newArray = immutableMyArray.set(index, myRow);

    setMyArray(newArray);


  };


  return (

    <ul>
      {
        myArray.map(function (val) {
          return (
            <li key={val.id}>
              <button onClick={updateRow} data-id={val.id}  >Update Title</button>
              {val.id} :  {val.interestLevel}
            </li>
          )
        })
      }
    </ul>

  )
}
```

Without Immutable.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default () => {

  const init = [{
    id: 101,
    interestLevel: 1
  },
  {
    id: 102, 
    interestLevel: 0
  }];

  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState(init);

  const updateRow = (e) => {
    const id = e.target.attributes['data-id'].value;
    const newMyArray = [...myArray];
    var index = newMyArray.findIndex(a=>a.id==id);
    newMyArray[index].interestLevel = myArray[index].interestLevel + 1;
    setMyArray(newMyArray);
  }


  return (

    <ul>
      {
        myArray.map(function (val) {
          return (
            <li key={val.id}>
              <button onClick={updateRow} data-id={val.id}  >Update Title</button>
              {val.id} :  {val.interestLevel}
            </li>
          )
        })
      }
    </ul>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the purpose of immutablejs?

In your example, you are only adding needless complexity to your code, without leveraging the gains provided by the library.

The purpose of immutable is to provide immutable collections, inspired from scala. In other words, you create your collection, then you pass it to another component, and you can be certain that *no element was appended or removed*. The individual elements, however, are not under such guarantee, partly due to the constraints (or lack thereof) brought by JS.

As it stands in your code, there are very few reasons to do something like this. I've taken the liberty of changing your quote quite a bit in order to showcase how to do so:

```js
class Comp extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(constructor);
    if (props.interests) {
      this.state = {
        interests: props.interests
      }
    } else {
      this.state = {
        interests: Immutable.Set([])
      }
    }
  }

  updateRow(e) {
    return function() {
      this.setState({
        interests: this.state.interests.update((elements) => {
          for (var element of elements) {
            if (element.id == e) {
              element.interestLevel++;
            }
          }
          return elements;
        })
      });
    }
  }


  render() {
    var interests = this.state.interests;
    var updateRow = this.updateRow;
    var list = this;
    //return (<div>Test</div>);
    return ( <
        ul > {
          interests.map(function(val) {
              return ( <
                  li key = {
                    val.id
                  } >
                  <
                  button onClick = {
                    updateRow(val.id).bind(list)
                  }
                  data-id = {
                    val.id
                  } > Update Title < /button> {
                  val.id
                }: {
                  val.interestLevel
                } <
                /li>
            )
          })
      } <
      /ul>

  )
}
}
var interests = Immutable.Set([{
    id: 1,
    interestLevel: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    interestLevel: 0
  }
])
ReactDOM.render( < Comp interests = {
      interests
    }
    />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/immutable@4.0.0-rc.12/dist/immutable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```

The changes:

1. Rewrote your component as a class. This is purely to highlight the rest of the changes
2. Your component now takes an external `prop` containing interests. This means you can pass a `Set` and be sure that it won't have elements added out of the blue within the component
3. The component is in charge of the interest levels. As such, whenever you click on one of the buttons, the `update` function is called on the `Set`, which is used to update the items inside the collection
4. The entire thing is rendered as an array through `render()`

This is both more readable and easier to manage.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but our real problem is a more complex, deeper object hierarchary. I want to use ImmutableJs because it avoids mistakes on state changes and I had understood that it's very efficient compared to trying to do it myself. Also, I need to stick with functions and React Hooks.

Comment: @PeterKellner as stated, rewriting it as a component was purely to be able to separate and highlight the different bits of the code. You can (and should, if you want to) turn it back into a closure. The same goes for using react hooks - you can replace the entire `updateRow` with basically a call to `setInterests` (where `[interests, setInterests] = useState(props.benefits)`. None of this is impacted, it's just easier to show the benefits when using a full-fledged class.

Comment: The strength of immutable is indeed that it clearly **shows** where you're modifying it (in my case, in the one and only call to `update`). This gain is not present in your code as you are effectively getting, then setting, each value, rather than noticing that you can do the entire thing in one atomic operation with a call to `update`

Comment: I'm sure this is brilliant code, but I'm just not following how it helps me. I'm seeing that you are creating a top level interests in state and changing that but I'm not following how I would apply this to anything but this example.  I have a complex list of objects that I need to poke changes in all different places and then make that new object my state.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918086/need-help-simplifying-an-immutable-js-array-of-objects-update#comment94680128_53918292), you're looking for easier ways of updating objects in a deep object hierarchy using Immutable.js.

[updateIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/updateIn) should do the trick.

```
const immutableObject = Immutable.fromJS({ outerProp: { innerCount: 1 } });
immutableObject.updateIn(['outerProp', 'innerCount'], count => count + 1);
```

It's also worth noting that you probably want to call `Immutable.fromJS()` instead of using `Immutable.List()` since the latter won't deeply convert your JavaScript object into an Immutable one, which can lead to bugs if you're assuming the data structure to be deeply Immutable. Switching the code above to use `Immutable.fromJS()` and `updateIn` we get:

```
// In updateRow
const immutableMyArray = fromJS(myArray);
const index = immutableMyArray.findIndex((item) => {
  return item.id === id;
});
const newArray = immutableMyArray.updateIn([index, 'interestLevel'], interestLevel => interestLevel + 1);

setMyArray(newArray);
```